# Qual è il contrario di tardo, nell'espressione "tardo Cretaceo"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, single-words

Mi erano venuta in mente anche le parole *basso* e *alto*, che si usano ad esempio per il medioevo, ma non mi viene in mente quale possa essere il contrario di "tardo".

Così la domanda è: *basso medioevo* sta ad *alto medioevo* come *tardo creataceo* sta a ...?

Answer (score 7):

Una breve ricerca su Google suggerisce che i termini d'arte in italiano siano *Cretaceo superiore* e *Cretaceo inferiore*.

Per la domanda più generale su quale sia la traduzione migliore di *early* in questo contesto, suggerirei *primo* (ad esempio *il primo Novecento*, indicando l'inizio del ventesimo secolo contrapposto al *tardo Novecento* che ne indica la fine) ma è un uso molto più raro in italiano che in altre lingue.

Per concludere uno potrebbe dire *nel primo/tardo Cretaceo* ma a quanto mi risulta non si tratta di un uso standard nella letteratura scientifica (anche se comprensibile).

Comment: Complimenti per aver capito che traducevo dall'inglese :D